# Create Button which stay permanently clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a Button which I can click and which stay clicked permanently as long as i click no other button.

Something like [this](https://abload.de/img/examplezkji5.png):

So that I can choose a color and switch colors. I want to use `HTML/Javascript`.

Comment: Do you mean the button remains active until you click another button? You can do that with css

Comment: I wouldn't use button tags, I would use radio inputs and CSS. You can have a radio for each color and style the input as a colored square and use the :checked CSS pseudo class to give the "color selected" style. You won't need javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code when clicked on the button.

```
document.getElementById('buttonID').style.borderStyle = 'inset';
```

For remove before button style and add to this on the new one.

```
document.getElementById('buttonID').style.borderStyle = 'outset';
document.getElementById('anotherButtonID').style.borderStyle = 'outset';
```

Hope, It will work.